# speed of setRegion for MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview, region

If I change the region in `setRegion` for an `MKMapView`, is there a way to set the speed, or duration, of that animation change? I've looked through the documentation and the Googles, but found nothing.

Comment: No, it isn't possible to change them.

Comment: Have you checked this: [Controlling the animation speed of MKMapView in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785529/controlling-the-animation-speed-of-mkmapview-in-ios6)

Answer (score 27):

And here's an easy to use Swift extension in case someone stumbles upon this in the future

```
import MapKit

extension MKMapView {
    func animatedZoom(zoomRegion zoomRegion:MKCoordinateRegion, duration:NSTimeInterval) {
        MKMapView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Update to Swift 5:

```
extension MKMapView {
    func animatedZoom(zoomRegion:MKCoordinateRegion, duration:TimeInterval) {
        MKMapView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks!

Comment: @beseder Agree!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to set the duration of the `setRegion` animation by editing the response to the question - [Setting the zoom level for a MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189621/setting-the-zoom-level-for-a-mkmapview) - as follows:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MKMapView (ZoomLevel)

- (void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerCoordinate
                   zoomLevel:(NSUInteger)zoomLevel
                   animated:(BOOL)animated;
@end



#import "MKMapView+ZoomLevel.h"

@implementation MKMapView (ZoomLevel)

#define ANIMATION_DURATION 0.5
- (void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerCoordinate
                      zoomLevel:(NSUInteger)zoomLevel animated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0, 360/pow(2,zoomLevel)*self.frame.size.width/256);
    [MKMapView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
        [self setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span) animated:YES];
    }];
}
```