# Controlling the animation speed of MKMapView in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, mkmapview, ios6

I'm trying to follow a car on a map view.

This code should animate the car and the map with the same speed, so that the annotation view always appears in the center:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

[car setCoordinate:coord];
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:coord];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**It worked fine in iOS 5. In iOS 6 the map is not animating anymore but the car does animate.**

I tried `[mapView setCenterCoordinate:co animated:YES]`, but then I cannot control the animation speed. It will always animate with the default duration (0.2s).

Comment: try `[mapView setCenterCoordinate:co animated:NO];`

Comment: @relikd I tried, this has the same effect as `[mapView setCenterCoordinate:co]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it is not possible to control the animation speed in iOS 6 when using these methods in `MKMapView`:

```
- (void)setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setVisibleMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect animated:(BOOL)animate;
- (void)setVisibleMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect edgePadding:(UIEdgeInsets)insets animated:(BOOL)animate;
```

However I found a private method that has a duration parameter. So I solved my issue by subclassing MKMapView and overriding the private method (which only exists in iOS6):

**MyMapView.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyMapView : MKMapView

@property(nonatomic) BOOL overridesAnimationDuration;
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval mapAnimationDuration;

@end
```

**MyMapView.m**

```
@interface MKMapView (Private)
- (void)_setZoomScale:(float)scale centerMapPoint:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center duration:(double)d animationType:(int)animType;
@end

@implementation MyMapView
- (void)_setZoomScale:(float)scale centerMapPoint:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center duration:(double)d animationType:(int)animType
{
    if (_overridesAnimationDuration) {
        d = _mapAnimationDuration;
    }
    [super _setZoomScale:scale centerMapPoint:center duration:d animationType:animType];
}    
@end
```

I've added 2 properties that allow you to override the default animation time.
To use it set `overridesAnimationDuration` to YES before a region change, set `mapAnimationDuration` to the desired duration and switch `overridesAnimationDuration` to NO in the delegate call `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`.

Note, this might not work in future iOS versions because it is private API. Apple can remove or change this method.

Comment: @jfisk i don't know, however 3 app updates with this code were approved with no problem

Comment: Does this still work for you? I have tried it, it does not work for me, overriding all works, but setting both properties (_mapAnimationDuration = 1.0, overridesAnimationDuration = YES) has no effect. Although the overridden methods are called!

Comment: I tested your code on iphone with ios5. The overidden method is called, too

Comment: what worked is to call [setCenterCoordinate:animated], but the animation type seems to be EaseInEaseOut, which is not ideal for this task, Do you use [setCenterCoordinate:animated] or the animation block?

Comment: I call `[mapView setCenterCoordinate:coord animated:YES]`.

Comment: are you happy with that solution? in ios5 it worked better. can you stop the animation, eg when the user wants to pinch-zoom?

Comment: I found out that setting the animation duration to a higher value than 0.2 makes it less probable that a pinch zoom or pan gesture works. settig to 0,5 sometimes zooms, setting to 0.9 ignores zooming and panning gestures. Have you solved that?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same kind of issue today. I think the problem does not rely on MKMapView, but the (new) way ios6 manages animations.

It seems that in ios6, if an animation occurs before a previous one has finished (depending on the run loop), the older gets interrupted by the new one. I think this only occurs if the "beginsFromCurrentState" option or property (depending if you are using block based animation or not) is used (by the new one).

To be sure, I think you should try to use block-based animation to see if your animation is really interrupted by another one.

This code must be equivalent to yours, and allows you to see if your animation has been interrupted or cancelled (if "finished" is false) :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0f options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{

    [car setCoordinate:coord];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:coord];

} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    NSLog(@"has not been interrupted : %d", finished);
}];
```

(in iOS < 6,"finished" should be true...)

In my case, it appeared that my animation was interrupted by the following UIViewController's methods, which was performed by the system in an animation block, interrupting my animation chain :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't help me. I tried it with block based UIView animation (with and without `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`). No matter what I do, I can not control the animation speed of the map view itself and the `finished` flag is always `YES`, because I animate every 3 seconds and the  animation duration is shorter (1 second), so it doesn't get interrupted.

Comment: +1 because it was informative, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: are you able to animate the map center for a delay of 1s?

Answer (score 7):

I found that the standard UIView AnimationWithDuration would apply if formatted like so:

```
// create a region with a center coordinate and a degree span
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.3601, longitude: -71.0689)
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.0, 1.0)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)

UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0,
             delay: 0.0,
           options: .CurveEaseInOut | .AllowUserInteraction,
        animations: {
                    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true);
        },
        completion: { finished in
                    println("completed 3 second animation to new region")
        })
```

Hope that works for you too! :)

(note: It was pointed out to me, that this response was geared towards iOS7/8 and that the question was for iOS6. )

---

And, this simple will actually work fine...

```
    let c = mkMap.userLocation.coordinate
    let r = CLLocationDistance( 1500 )
    let cr = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance( c, r, r )

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.4, animations: { [weak self] in

        self?.mkMap.setRegion( cr, animated: true)
    })
```

Comment: This question was iOS 6 specific.  I bet you did not test it on iOS 6, because Swift code does not run on older iOS versions.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have read more carefully. (I'll note that this is iOS 7/8 safe)