# how to find current zoom level of MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I want to know the current zoom level of `MKMapView` in iphone programming, how can I do that?
Actually I have one app, that is taking few arguments(Radius from center to corner of `MKMapView`) are returning the store details in that are, when I am on `MKMapView`, the radius is very high and it changes when Radius is smaller, so I want to know the zoom level and setup my webservice according to that, How can I get zoom level of current `MKMapView` visible area?

Comment: Just check answer from
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `span` inside the `region` property of the `MKMapView`. It is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta;
} MKCoordinateSpan;
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205). It is well explained there.

Answer (score 52):

I created very simple helper subclass for it:

```
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395
#define MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS 20

@interface MKMapView (ZoomLevel)
- (double)getZoomLevel;
@end

@implementation MKMapView (ZoomLevel)

- (double)getZoomLevel
{
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = self.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    CGFloat mapWidthInPixels = self.bounds.size.width;
    double zoomScale = longitudeDelta * MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * mapWidthInPixels);
    double zoomer = MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS - log2( zoomScale );
    if ( zoomer < 0 ) zoomer = 0;
//  zoomer = round(zoomer);
    return zoomer;
}

@end
```

Comment: I think MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS can be obtained from `MKMapSizeWorld.width / 256` and take the log2 of that where 256 is the tile width or tile height in pixel (or maybe point)

Comment: That is log2(MKMapSizeWorld.width / 256)

Comment: to stick to Objective C standards, the method's name should be zoomLevel instead of getZoomLevel.

Comment: Simplest way is to create a category:

https://gist.github.com/d2burke/ad29811b07ae31b378ff

(credit to Nikita Galayko @NiKe

Answer (score 13):

All the previous answers do not take into consideration current map rotation. MKMapView's longitudeDelta differs for non-rotated map and rotated map.
Here is a great function for straight map zoom calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15020534/4923516

And here is my improvement in Swift, that takes into consideration map rotation and returns current zoom level:

```
class MyMapView : MKMapView {

  func getZoom() -> Double {
    // function returns current zoom of the map
    var angleCamera = self.camera.heading
    if angleCamera > 270 {
        angleCamera = 360 - angleCamera
    } else if angleCamera > 90 {
        angleCamera = fabs(angleCamera - 180)
    }
    let angleRad = M_PI * angleCamera / 180 // camera heading in radians
    let width = Double(self.frame.size.width)
    let height = Double(self.frame.size.height)
    let heightOffset : Double = 20 // the offset (status bar height) which is taken by MapKit into consideration to calculate visible area height
    // calculating Longitude span corresponding to normal (non-rotated) width
    let spanStraight = width * self.region.span.longitudeDelta / (width * cos(angleRad) + (height - heightOffset) * sin(angleRad))
    return log2(360 * ((width / 256) / spanStraight)) + 1;
  }

}
```

You can download sample project in my repo: https://github.com/d-babych/mapkit-wrap

Comment: This code helped me, although I omitted the heightOffset concept because I do not think it is applicable to my situation (my MKMapView does not cover the entire screen).

Comment: How can this be done for SwiftUI?

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to get an Integer of the current zoom level, is by using the MapView function: regionDidChangeAnimated. This function recognizes every change in zoom and will give you the basis for the calculation of the zoom factor.

Just insert this function into your MapView class (**works for Swift 3.0**):

```
var mapView: MKMapView! = nil

...

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let zoomWidth = mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width
    let zoomFactor = Int(log2(zoomWidth)) - 9
    print("...REGION DID CHANGE: ZOOM FACTOR \(zoomFactor)")
}
```

And you will get a zoomFactor value out of it, where 0 is the most near point you can zoom into the map and every higher value is a far far away zoom... :-)

Comment: Why - 9 at the zoomFactor?

Comment: The 9 is not necessary, it is just for the case if you want to end-up the maximum zoom factor to 0.... without the 9, in my case it will end with 9.

Comment: That would make the -9 necessary because this is how the standard zoom level works.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps you can also use `mapView.camera.altitude` to get the current altitude of the currently displayed map region.

This is what helped me when I searched how to get the map zoom level.