# MKMapView center and zoom in

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I am using MKMapView on a project and would like to center the map on a coordinate and zoom in. Just like Google maps has:

```
GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.8683,
                                  longitude: 151.2086,
                                  zoom: 6)
```

Is there any Mapkit method for this?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a method I use to center your map on a pre-defined `CLLocation` using `MKCoordinateRegion`.

```
func centerMapOnLocation(_ location: CLLocation, mapView: MKMapView) {
    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
        regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You should refactor this function into an instance method on MKMapView.

Answer (score 9):

You'd create a MKCoordinateRegion object and set that as the region on your MKMapView object.

```
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = 0;
coordinate.longitude = 0;    
mapRegion.center = coordinate;
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

[mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

Put the below code in your `CustomMapView` subclass of `MKMapView`
Call is from `init`

```
class CustomMapView: MKMapView {
private func zoom() {
            let dortmundLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 51.516667, longitude: 7.466667)
            let dortmunRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dortmundLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: dortmundLocation.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
            self.setRegion(dortmunRegion, animated: true)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Code based on : http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/

```
    extension MKMapView {
    var MERCATOR_OFFSET : Double {
        return 268435456.0
    }

    var MERCATOR_RADIUS : Double  {
        return 85445659.44705395
    }

    private func longitudeToPixelSpaceX(longitude: Double) -> Double {
        return round(MERCATOR_OFFSET + MERCATOR_RADIUS * longitude * M_PI / 180.0)
    }

    private func latitudeToPixelSpaceY(latitude: Double) -> Double {
        return round(MERCATOR_OFFSET - MERCATOR_RADIUS * log((1 + sin(latitude * M_PI / 180.0)) / (1 - sin(latitude * M_PI / 180.0))) / 2.0)
    }

    private  func pixelSpaceXToLongitude(pixelX: Double) -> Double {
        return ((round(pixelX) - MERCATOR_OFFSET) / MERCATOR_RADIUS) * 180.0 / M_PI;
    }

    private func pixelSpaceYToLatitude(pixelY: Double) -> Double {
        return (M_PI / 2.0 - 2.0 * atan(exp((round(pixelY) - MERCATOR_OFFSET) / MERCATOR_RADIUS))) * 180.0 / M_PI;
    }

    private func coordinateSpan(withMapView mapView: MKMapView, centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoomLevel: UInt) ->MKCoordinateSpan {
        let centerPixelX = longitudeToPixelSpaceX(centerCoordinate.longitude)
        let centerPixelY = latitudeToPixelSpaceY(centerCoordinate.latitude)

        let zoomExponent = Double(20 - zoomLevel)
        let zoomScale = pow(2.0, zoomExponent)

        let mapSizeInPixels = mapView.bounds.size
        let scaledMapWidth =  Double(mapSizeInPixels.width) * zoomScale
        let scaledMapHeight = Double(mapSizeInPixels.height) * zoomScale

        let topLeftPixelX = centerPixelX - (scaledMapWidth / 2);
        let topLeftPixelY = centerPixelY - (scaledMapHeight / 2);

        //    // find delta between left and right longitudes
        let minLng = pixelSpaceXToLongitude(topLeftPixelX)
        let maxLng = pixelSpaceXToLongitude(topLeftPixelX + scaledMapWidth)
        let longitudeDelta = maxLng - minLng;

        let minLat = pixelSpaceYToLatitude(topLeftPixelY)
        let maxLat = pixelSpaceYToLatitude(topLeftPixelY + scaledMapHeight)
        let latitudeDelta = -1 * (maxLat - minLat);

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta)
        return span
    }

    func zoom(toCenterCoordinate centerCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D ,zoomLevel: UInt) {
        let zoomLevel = min(zoomLevel, 20)
        let span = self.coordinateSpan(withMapView: self, centerCoordinate: centerCoordinate, zoomLevel: zoomLevel)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span)
        self.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

<sub>**Apinho** answer in Swift 4.x</sub>

```
 extension MKMapView {

    var MERCATOR_OFFSET : Double {
        return 268435456.0
    }

    var MERCATOR_RADIUS : Double  {
        return 85445659.44705395
    }

    private func longitudeToPixelSpaceX(longitude: Double) -> Double {
        return round(MERCATOR_OFFSET + MERCATOR_RADIUS * longitude * Double.pi / 180.0)
    }

    private func latitudeToPixelSpaceY(latitude: Double) -> Double {
        return round(MERCATOR_OFFSET - MERCATOR_RADIUS * log((1 + sin(latitude * Double.pi / 180.0)) / (1 - sin(latitude * Double.pi / 180.0))) / 2.0)
    }

    private  func pixelSpaceXToLongitude(pixelX: Double) -> Double {
        return ((round(pixelX) - MERCATOR_OFFSET) / MERCATOR_RADIUS) * 180.0 / Double.pi;
    }

    private func pixelSpaceYToLatitude(pixelY: Double) -> Double {
        return (Double.pi / 2.0 - 2.0 * atan(exp((round(pixelY) - MERCATOR_OFFSET) / MERCATOR_RADIUS))) * 180.0 / Double.pi;
    }

    private func coordinateSpan(withMapView mapView: MKMapView, centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoomLevel: UInt) ->MKCoordinateSpan {
        let centerPixelX = longitudeToPixelSpaceX(longitude: centerCoordinate.longitude)
        let centerPixelY = latitudeToPixelSpaceY(latitude: centerCoordinate.latitude)

        let zoomExponent = Double(20 - zoomLevel)
        let zoomScale = pow(2.0, zoomExponent)

        let mapSizeInPixels = mapView.bounds.size
        let scaledMapWidth =  Double(mapSizeInPixels.width) * zoomScale
        let scaledMapHeight = Double(mapSizeInPixels.height) * zoomScale

        let topLeftPixelX = centerPixelX - (scaledMapWidth / 2);
        let topLeftPixelY = centerPixelY - (scaledMapHeight / 2);

        // find delta between left and right longitudes
        let minLng = pixelSpaceXToLongitude(pixelX: topLeftPixelX)
        let maxLng = pixelSpaceXToLongitude(pixelX: topLeftPixelX + scaledMapWidth)
        let longitudeDelta = maxLng - minLng;

        let minLat = pixelSpaceYToLatitude(pixelY: topLeftPixelY)
        let maxLat = pixelSpaceYToLatitude(pixelY: topLeftPixelY + scaledMapHeight)
        let latitudeDelta = -1 * (maxLat - minLat);

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta)
        return span
    }

    func zoom(toCenterCoordinate centerCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoomLevel: UInt) {
        let zoomLevel = min(zoomLevel, 20)
        let span = self.coordinateSpan(withMapView: self, centerCoordinate: centerCoordinate, zoomLevel: zoomLevel)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span)
        self.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is working code tested on swift 4.2**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 28.5761897, longitude: 77.172080)
    self.centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)
}


 func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

This will load with animation. Hope will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

In the MapKit Function `didUpdateLocations`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            guard let location = locations.last as CLLocation? else { return }

            let userCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            // Does not have to be userCenter, could replace latitude: and longitude: with any value you would like to center in on

            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userCenter, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 180, longitudeDelta: 180))

            mkView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
```

Note: If you do not want to keep setting the center every time there is a location update, then do the following:

```
        let userCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        // Does not have to be userCenter, could replace latitude: and longitude: with any value you would like to center in on

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userCenter, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 180, longitudeDelta: 180))

        mkView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in swift 5, ios 13

Just add the following method to your class:

```
func zoomAndCenter(on centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoom: Double) {
    var span: MKCoordinateSpan = mapView.region.span
    span.latitudeDelta *= zoom
    span.longitudeDelta *= zoom
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerCoordinate, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on apinho answer.
This option follows Swift 5 syntax and allows to use it as an initializer of MKCoordinateRegion, so can be used in other objects beside MKMapView for example in MKMapSnapshotter.

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {

    init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoom: UInt, bounds: CGRect) {
        let zoom = min(zoom, 20)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(center: center, zoom: zoom, bounds: bounds)
        self.init(center: center, span: span)
    }
}

extension MKCoordinateSpan {

    static var mercatorOffset: Double {
        return 268435456.0
    }

    static var mercatorRadius: Double {
        return 85445659.44705395
    }

    private static func longitudeToPixelSpaceX(longitude: Double) -> Double {
        return round(mercatorOffset + mercatorRadius * longitude * Double.pi / 180.0)
    }

    private static func latitudeToPixelSpaceY(latitude: Double) -> Double {
        return round(mercatorOffset - mercatorRadius * log((1 + sin(latitude * Double.pi / 180.0)) / (1 - sin(latitude * Double.pi / 180.0))) / 2.0)
    }

    private static func pixelSpaceXToLongitude(pixelX: Double) -> Double {
        return ((round(pixelX) - mercatorOffset) / mercatorRadius) * 180.0 / Double.pi
    }

    private static func pixelSpaceYToLatitude(pixelY: Double) -> Double {
        return (Double.pi / 2.0 - 2.0 * atan(exp((round(pixelY) - mercatorOffset) / mercatorRadius))) * 180.0 / Double.pi
    }

    init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoom: UInt, bounds: CGRect) {

        let centerPixelX = MKCoordinateSpan.longitudeToPixelSpaceX(longitude: center.longitude)
        let centerPixelY = MKCoordinateSpan.latitudeToPixelSpaceY(latitude: center.latitude)

        let zoomExponent = Double(20 - zoom)
        let zoomScale = pow(2.0, zoomExponent)

        let mapSizeInPixels = bounds.size
        let scaledMapWidth =  Double(mapSizeInPixels.width) * zoomScale
        let scaledMapHeight = Double(mapSizeInPixels.height) * zoomScale

        let topLeftPixelX = centerPixelX - (scaledMapWidth / 2)
        let topLeftPixelY = centerPixelY - (scaledMapHeight / 2)

        // find delta between left and right longitudes
        let minLng = MKCoordinateSpan.pixelSpaceXToLongitude(pixelX: topLeftPixelX)
        let maxLng = MKCoordinateSpan.pixelSpaceXToLongitude(pixelX: topLeftPixelX + scaledMapWidth)
        let longitudeDelta = maxLng - minLng

        let minLat = MKCoordinateSpan.pixelSpaceYToLatitude(pixelY: topLeftPixelY)
        let maxLat = MKCoordinateSpan.pixelSpaceYToLatitude(pixelY: topLeftPixelY + scaledMapHeight)
        let latitudeDelta = -1 * (maxLat - minLat)

        self.init(latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta)
    }
}
```